# Проблема с Data annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, upload, viewmodel

При добавлении новости `ModelState.IsValid` всегда `false`.

**Модель**:

```
public class NewsViewModelItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Short Title")]
    public string ShortTitle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Full Title")]
    public string FullTitle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Short Article")]
    public string ShortArticle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Full Article")]
    public string FullArticle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual List<NewsImageModelItem> NewsImages { get; set; }

}
```

Выдает ошибку из-за `NewsImages`.

> The parameter conversion from type '**System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper**'
>   to type '**Schedule.BLL.Model.NewsImageModelItem**' failed because no type
>   converter can convert between these types.

Мне бы хотелось понять, как пропускать `NewsImages` в `Data annotation`, либо как-то по другому решить эту проблему.

Comment: А что вы имеете ввиду, когда пишете `[Required] public virtual List<NewsImageModelItem> NewsImages { get; set; }` - коллекция требуется? Ну так вы напишите типа `public virtual List<NewsImageModelItem> NewsImages { get; } = new List<NewsImageModelItem>()`, атрибут тут не нужен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте собственный атрибут от ValidationAttribute
и переопределите в нем поведение для IsValid (своя логика для вашей коллекции NewsImageModelItem)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc679289(v=vs.110).aspx

и уже дальше можете поменять ваше свойство

```
[MyRequired]
public virtual List<NewsImageModelItem> NewsImages { get; set; }
```

Ваш код будет примерно следующий:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class MyRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        bool result;
        var collection = (List<NewsImageModelItem>)value;
        if (collection == null || collection.Count == 0)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        else
            result = true;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Если VS не может найти using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; добавьте руками ссылку на данную DLL в проект.

Comment: А если коллекция не `List` будет, а другая какая-нибудь? Еще один атрибут делать?

Comment: Зря отредактировали, т.к. не всегда VS предлагает сама добавить DLL в проект и нужно руками ссылку вставлять. к примеру у меня так сейчас и было.

Comment: У вас там дублирование одной и той же информации было, зачем?

Comment: var collection = (List<NewsImageModelItem>)value;    
if (collection == null)
 
тут можно несколько параметров перепроверять.